# Blueberries (SPOJ) - Dynamic Programming Time Limit Exceeded

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I was solving a [problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/RPLB/) on spoj. Problem has a simple recursive solution.

Problem: Given an array of numbers of size **n**, select a set of numbers such that **no two elements in the set are consecutive** and **sum of subset elements will be as close as possible to k**, but should not exceed it.

My Recursive Approach

I used a approach similar to knapsack, at dividing the problem such that one includes the current element and other ignores it.

```
  function solve_recursively(n, current, k)
     if n < 0
        return current
     if n == 0
        if current + a[n] <= k
           return current + a[n]
        else
           return current
     if current + a[n] > k
        return recurse(n-1, current, k)
     else
        return max(recurse(n-1, current, k), recurse(n-2, current+a[n], k))
```

Later as it is exponential in nature, I used map (in C++) to do memoization to reduce complexity.

My source code:

```
struct k{
  int n; 
  int curr;
};

bool operator < (const struct k& lhs, const struct k& rhs){
  if(lhs.n != rhs.n)
    return lhs.n < rhs.n;
  return lhs.curr < rhs.curr;
};

int a[1001];
map<struct k,int> dp;

int recurse(int n, int k, int curr){
  if(n < 0)
    return curr;
  struct k key = {n, curr};
  if(n == 0)
    return curr + a[0] <= k ? curr + a[0] : curr;
  else if(dp.count(key))
    return dp[key];
  else if(curr + a[n] > k){
    dp[key] = recurse(n-1, k, curr);
    return dp[key];
  }
  else{
    dp[key] = max(recurse(n-1, k, curr), recurse(n-2, k, curr+a[n]));
    return dp[key];
  }
}

int main(){
  int t,n,k;
  scanint(t);
  while(t--){
    scanint(n);
    scanint(k);
    for(int i = 0; i<n; ++i)
      scanint(a[i]);
    dp.clear();
    printf("Scenario #%d: %d\n",j, recurse(n-1, k, 0));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I checked for given test cases. It cleared them. But I am getting wrong answer on submission.

**EDIT:** Earlier my output format was wrong, so I was getting Wrong Answer. But, now its showing **Time Limit Exceeded**. I think bottom-up approach would be helpful, but I am having problem in formulating one. I am approaching it as bottom-up knapsack, but having some difficulties in exact formulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding, you almost have the solution. If the recurrence relation is correct but too inefficient, you just have change the recursion to iteration. Apparently, you already have the array `dp` which represents the states and their respective values. Basically you should be able to solve fill `dp` with three nested loops for `n`, `k` and `curr`, which would increase respectively to ensure that each value from `dp` which is needed has already been calculated. Then you replace the recursive calls to `recurse` with accesses to `dp`.

Comment: Thanks. Working on it now.

Comment: It would perhaps be easier if you changed the signature of `recurse` to `int recurse(struct k, int curr)` or use a three-dimensional array for `dp`.

Comment: Solved. But I done it in a slightly different way. I used an array dp[n][k], where dp[i][j] denotes the max value attainable which is less than or equal to j using first i elements. And filled it in bottom up approach. Thanks anyways. :D

Comment: @Codor: Nearly -- you want `int recurse(int n, int k)`, and to subtract from `k` at each recursive call.